# Why does webapi 2 fail pre-flight options request from IIS

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

I have a very simple webapi 2 application that is just a passthrough to a com dll and is working for Get requests but failing the one Post request with a CORS error when I run the api on localhost in IIS.  It works when I run the client in a node server and the server in IIS Express from Visual Studio each running on a different localhost port.

I have CORS globally enabled in my webapiconfig.cs file:
public static class WebApiConfig

```
      public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
      {
         // Web API configuration and services

         // Web API routes
         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

         var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
         config.EnableCors(cors);

         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/v1.0/{controller}"
         );
      }
```

When I make the http request from angular with the server running in IIS on localhost I get the following errors
[image: Error displayed in console]

And this is what the network traffic looks like
[image]

It has been working until recently.  The only changes I have made are in the client and the com dll.  But the post works fine from Fiddler.  I am a relative novice at http, so can someone suggest how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it since?

Comment: The error message was erroneous.  The problem was actually an error in the com server that I ended up finding another way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not problem of the CORS config itself. It seems to be OK. Double check your routes in WEB API. I think you have to change your route how you access the resource.

Comment: The only route in the application is in the code in the question